# Flash Builder 4: Variable not displaying in debug window (Variables tab)

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

In my flex 3.5 project, I have a class (`MyItem`) extending `Canvas`. In this I have declared a private variable named `itemInfo` which is type of `ItemInfo` (which is another subclass of `Canvas`).

I wrote code to hide/show the `iteminfo` when the mouse is over/out of `MyItem`. I am not getting any error but it is not showing the `itemInfo` as expected, when debugged the code, surprisingly the variables tab in debug window does not have the variable `itemInfo` at all.

I have declared a `dummy:int` variable and it is also not visible.

I am stuck please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've only ever seen this behavior with `const`s, never with `var`s.

Comment: have to tried to check the variable in "this"?

Comment: @umar yes. thats where I searched. I even removed some variables (thinking could be a limitation of number of variables I can have in a class) and tried but not visible.

Comment: @RIAstar what was the solution/workaround for that?

Comment: mate, the problem is , u are not reaching the point where the variable is getting created. Can u please link the code here? A small bit of it.

Comment: @dev2dev Other than temporarily making it a 'var' when debugging, I found none.

Comment: @umar its a class level variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after the frustrating hours and sleepless night I came back and restarted the FB and it started working.

Just to let you know I did cleared build, reboot the system last day. More surprisingly I was getting same error when I started a new project (IN THE SAME WORKSPACE) and it was not detecting any variables I declared. which was pathetic. I then created a new project in the NEW WORKSPACE and it started detecting the variables and I switched back to the originial workspace and got it working. I dont know exactly which one has corrected it but this is all what I have did.

Answer (score 0):

Often, especially if you have a class declared in actionscript with a mxml implementation, variables can be buried in the "inherited" section.

Failing that, have you tried using a trace?

Comment: I am not sure if this surpises you or not but entire line where ever the variable is used will not be executed. I have even wrote Alert.show but it does nothing there. and yes, its not mxml and I also searchd the inherited section